# Drupal How to add javascript to ctools modal popup

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I need to hide some element with some condition using jquery inside ctools modal popup in drupal after popup load. I used `drupal_add_js` but that not work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use: `ctools_ajax_command_attr('selector','attr','value');` do perform any kind of actions in popup. For more you can read: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!includes!ajax.inc/7

Answer (score 0):

into custom modal style where you outputing your page callback add
    ctools_add_js('your_js_file_without_extension', 'MODULE_NAME');

then in js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.MODULE_NAME = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

     //your jquery code...

  }
}; });
```

For example you can copy ctools-ajax-samples.js from ctools directory and modify it as i did. This solution worked for me